# Looping through worksheets, refreshing and sorting pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to create a macro to loop through all worksheets in a workbook, determine if there is a pivot table, refresh that pivot table, and sort on a specific column. There are a number of sheets that won't be sorted on a specific column so I have included code to exclude them.

It seems that it is only sorting the pivot table on the `ActiveSheet`. I think this is because of the `ActiveSheet.PivotTable(1)` piece, but the code won't run if I take that piece out. I'm fairly new to VBA, so I'm at a loss for what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub RefreshPivotCache()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PT As PivotTable

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets '<~~ Loop all worksheets in workbook
        If ws.PivotTables.Count > 0 Then
              If (ws.Name <> "L&D TE Summary") And (ws.Name <> "L&D BCD Summary") And (ws.Name <> "HR Ops TE") And (ws.Name <> "HR Ops BCD") And (ws.Name <> "Strat Delivery Summary") _
                And (ws.Name <> "Strat Delivery TE") And (ws.Name <> "Strat Delivery BCD") Then
                    For Each PT In ws.PivotTables        '<~~ Loop all pivot tables in worksheet
                        PT.PivotCache.Refresh
                       ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Associate Name").AutoSort _
                         xlDescending, " ", ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotColumnAxis. _
                         PivotLines(1), 1

                     Next PT
                End If
        End If

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only changing the pivot table on your `Activesheet`, but you never activate `ws` in your loop. So change

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Associate Name").AutoSort _
                         xlDescending, " ", ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotColumnAxis. _
                         PivotLines(1), 1
```

to

```
ws.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Associate Name").AutoSort _
                         xlDescending, " ", ws.PivotTables(1).PivotColumnAxis. _
                         PivotLines(1), 1
```

Comment: When I make the change it give me Run-tie error 5: invalid procedure call or argument on that line of code.

Comment: @Anp93 Also probably because you're attempting to do a `For Each` loop for pivot tables, but always referring to `PivotTable(1)`. Instead you should probably do a `For i = 1 to ws.PivotTables.Count`, then change `PivotTables(1)` to `PivotTables(i)`

Comment: Actually just replace `PivotTables(1)` with `PT`.

Comment: @Anp93 Glad to help!