# Sorting similarly structured pivot tables in different worksheets, in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am a complete VBA macro newbie but am trying to figure out what a VBA macro would be to sort all pivot tables in all worksheets of a workbook, where all the pivot tables have the same structure.

All the pivot tables are structured as:

```
Description | Date 2 months ago | Last Month's Date | This Month's Date

A               Some Value             Some Value        Some Value
B               Some Value             Some Value        Some Value
.
.
.
Z               Some Value             Some Value        Some Value
```

I want to sort each pivot table based on Descending order of 'Last Month's Date' column, which essentially also changes every month, based on Data source for pivot tables

Can someone please help with what such VBA code might look like?

I have tried the solution here: [Looping through worksheets, refreshing and sorting pivot tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323900/looping-through-worksheets-refreshing-and-sorting-pivot-tables)

and many others but always run into errors.

Any help is strongly appreciated! Thank you!

Update: I also recorded a macro as I was manually doing the steps, which had the below result in VBA:

```
Sub sort_pivot()


ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable_Name").PivotFields("Column_1").Orientation _
    = xlHidden
Range("DB12").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable_Name").PivotFields("Column_2"). _
    AutoSort xlDescending, "Name of Value", ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable_Name").PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(56), 1
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable_Name").PivotFields("Column_1")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

End Sub
```

This had a few steps of function though:

1. Remove Column_1 from 'Rows' selection from Pivot Table field list to
   allow sorting
2. Select value in DB12 cell reference
3. Sort entire table based on DB12 cell reference selection in Descending order
4. Put Column_1 back in 'Rows' selection in Pivot Table field list

Comment: What's the problem with the answer to in the link?

Comment: @SJR : I keep getting run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method